# C++ get current file running exe

Tags: c++

So, I've now fought with this for 2 days, still the same error.
I've been on over 300 results with google, still same FAILURE. It shows up as HEX all the time or it doesn't work at all.

This is not using any external librarys and no .net framework.
100% non-dependent.

I've tried over 30 methods.
`TCHAR szExeFileName[MAX_PATH];`
`GetModuleFileName(NULL, szExeFileName, MAX_PATH);`

^ Doesn't work; returns hex.
The code is in a void.

```
        #include "SharedHeader.h"
    #include <Psapi.h>
    #include "CommandLine_Pres.h"
    #include <TlHelp32.h>
using namespace std;

void filePath()
{
    // Figure out file path of current file
    char cCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
    if(!GetCurrentDir(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath)))
    {
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }
    cCurrentPath[sizeof(cCurrentPath) -1] = '\0';
    cout << cCurrentPath << endl;
    // Get process id, filename
    //cout << GetCommandLine();
    int procId = GetCurrentProcessId();
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetNativeSystemInfo(&si);
    /*
    DOES NOT WORK BELOW [debug]
    HANDLE Handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE,GetCurrentProcessId());
    if(Handle)
    {
        TCHAR Buffer[MAX_PATH];
        if(GetModuleFileNameEx(Handle, 0, Buffer, MAX_PATH))
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
        CloseHandle(Handle);
    }*/
}
```

Comment: What about `argv[0]`?  `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {/* use argv[0] */}`

Comment: Evgeny: Same, it outputs hex value. It doesn't work at all. Also, the code there is from void filePath() whihc is in a remote .cpp file outside of the Main.cpp I have. So it won't work anyways.

Comment: Please compile and run, and post output:
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) { std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;  return 0; }

Comment: That's a bug, the standard says argv[0] should be the name of the executable. What's your environment?

Comment: First I don't believe for a second  you even *tried* the comment JRG said, at least not *verbatim*. Secondly, the "hex" value you're referring to is likely a pointer, and the reason you're seeing it is because you're compiling under Unicode settings, and writing a `TCHAR *` to `std::cout`. (hint: `TCHAR Buffer[MAX_PATH];`) Either change your compilation settings to use non-unicode compilation or change the stdout you're writing on to `std::wcout`. And the next time someone suggests you try something, make an effort to actually *try it*, or at least don't make it so obvious you *didn't*.

Comment: I did try it first of all, so maybe you could tone it down a bit Whoz?

Comment: And your compilation settings regarding Unicode? Forgive the likely repetitive question, but since we're not privy to the exact, or even general, steps amongst the 30+ you have attempted, you're bound to get a high signal-to-noise ratio of been-there-done-that suggestions. If you tried JRGs suggestion *verbatim* and Unicode compilation was **on**  the project won't link, because `_wmain` will not resolve. If you tried with with the boilerplate `_tmain` and `_TCHAR` macros that MS uses (iow **not** verbatim to his post) it will build, but your output will be exactly what you are reporting.

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {cout << argv[0] << endl; } result: C

Answer (score 0):

To get the address of the current running process you can use:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
    std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl; 

    getchar();

    return 0; 
}
```

or:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{ 
    char szExeFileName[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szExeFileName, MAX_PATH);

    std::cout << szExeFileName;

    getchar();

    return 0; 
}
```